# In the following function, I want to reverse the linkedlist, but I am wondering where can I delete node?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

In the following function, I want to reverse the linkedlist, but I am wondering *where can I delete node?*

```
LinkedList reverse(LinkedList l){ 
   LinkedList res;
   while(l.getHead()){
     Node * node = new Node(l.getHead()->item); /*create a new node with item 
      of current head of l*/
     node->next = res.getHead();/*set the next pointer of node to current head 
      of res*/
     res.setHead(node); /*set node as new head of res*/
     l.setHead(l.getHead()->next); /*move to next node in l*/
   }
   return res;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete the node after

```
l.setHead(l.getHead()->next); /*move to next node in l*/
```

But you need a reference to that node first. So you would need to save it in a variable like

```
LinkedList *ｔｍｐ　＝　ｌ.getHead();
```

before the line of `l.setHead(...)`.